# search in appropriate Mysql fields based on current App Locale in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In a multilingual website I have these fields for **Products** table

```
product_id
title_fa
title_en
title_ar
desc_fa
desc_en
desc_ar
.
.
.
```

Now I want to search in (for Example) **title** fields based on Current laravel Locale.
I know that we can use this way :

```
$products   =   Product::where('title_'.App::getLocale(),'LIKE' , '%'.$data['search_value'].'%');
```

But I thinks that is not clean and easy for number of large fields is not suitable.

I'm looking for a way that was and simple as normal search field and then laravel search based on that field in background According to current App Locale like:

```
$products   =   Product::where('title','LIKE' , '%'.$data['search_value'].'%');
```

How Can I do that and what is best way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if you want really easy way for search products than use this following laravel multi language package

https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable

in this package you have to create 2 tables one Product and Product_translate, product table will have your basic product info, translate will have language data, in product_translate table you can use search queries, ease is table column name will remain same in where you have use language filter.

Comment: I use it before. but this package need an additional table for all tables that are translatable. working with it is not easy.

Comment: i am using this package for my project, saving retrieving data is easy, for search you need to create custom sql query.

Comment: I think that using `https://github.com/themsaid/laravel-multilingual` is easier that `https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable` package beacause does not need addition tables and use `json` formatted Mysql fields.

Comment: yes its good but its just new package and it will work with only MYSQL 5.7 only